# How to display conversation text in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to display text like below, how can I store it in database, should I have put by hand like `<p>, <br />` right? It will be take a lot of time, there are another way to do that, thank you!

**Tess**: Thank you.

**Ravi**: Are you doing anything special?

**Tess**: Well, I’m going out for dinner with some friends tonight and then we might go to a club. I’m not really sure.

**Ravi**: Sounds good. Where are you going to eat? Is it somewhere a bit special or …

Comment: You might consider something like Markdown, or a WYSIWYG editor. At its simplest (and fairly ugly resulting HTML) you can run it through PHP's `nl2br` function.

Comment: https://codepen.io/shivapandey/pen/dWdRYM https://codepen.io/mrana/full/OJbRyRB

Comment: Thank for giving me ideal !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/) for this. It will give you content in HTML format. You just need to write as a document editor. for example in the StackOverflow question and answer section, you are can design the document as **bold**, *italic*, [hyperlink](https://example.com), etc.
There are lots of WYSIWYG editors, for example, TinyMCE, Summernote, etc.

Comment: oh! I see! I'll do it. Thank for helping me!